# Не работает Java script на странице с расширением php

Tags: php, javascript

Помогите пожалуйста! Имеется скрипт (java script) встроенный в php-страницу

(скрипт должен менять текстовые смайлы на графические)
Java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
запускаем скрипт, который заменяет текстовые смайлики на графические после загрузки страницы
*/
window.onload = function(){
    smiley_replace();
}
/*

В многомерном массиве smiley хранится информация, необходимая для работы скрипта:

- регулярное выражение, с помощью которого скрипт будет находить текстовые смайлики;
- имя картинки с графическим смайликом;
- альтернативный текст, который будет показываться, если картинка по каким-то причинам не загрузится.

*/
smiley = new Array([/:-?\)+/gi,"smiles/1.gif",":-)"],[/:-?\(+/gi,"sad.gif",":-("]);
/*

функция, которая и будет заменять текстовые смайлы на графические
*/
function smiley_replace(){
    for(i=0;i<smiley.length;i++){
        document.getElementById("mytxt").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mytxt").innerHTML.replace(smiley[i][0], '<img src="'+smiley[i][1]+'" alt="'+smiley[i][0]+'"/>');
    }
}
</script>
```

Сам скрипт отлично работает в html странице, а на php не работает. Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, в чём проблема и есть ли из неё выход.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){
 smiley_replace();
}

smiley = new Array([/:-?\)+/gi,"smiles/1.gif",":-)"],[/:-?\(+/gi,"sad.gif",":-("]);

function smiley_replace(){
 for(i=0;i<smiley.length;i++){
  document.getElementById("mytxt").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mytxt").innerHTML.replace(smiley[i][0], '<img src="'+smiley[i][1]+'" alt="'+smiley[i][0]+'"/>');
 }
}
</script>

Comment: А страницу запускаете на сервере? Или нет? -_-

Comment: Страницу запускаю на серрвере разумеется:-)

Comment: Какие ошибки в консоли пишет?

Comment: никаких, всё пусто (просто нужно чтобы например символ ;-) заменялся на смайлик (картинку)

Comment: а зачем вы в альт вставляете регулярку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ваш РНР-скрипт, который Вы, кстати, не показали, делает какую-то выборку из базы данных, а Ваш текст, обрамленный в `id="mytext"` - это какая-то запись из таблицы (к примеру, комментарий), и она не одна, то Ваш скрипт не будет работать в принципе, потому-что **`id` может применяться для определения одного, и только одного элемента на всю страницу**, а **класс может использоваться для определения нескольких элементов, или группы элементов**.

Это одна из потенциальных проблем. Если я не прав, дайте мне знать. И, что интересно, консоль браузера никаких ошибок по этому поводу выдавать не будет

Comment: ну по крайней мере один элемент бы заменился